# Draw tree in Delphi

Tags: delphi, tree, draw

i'm new in delphi and i want to know some useful instruction that help me to draw this tree 
I have write this program and test the string if it prefix or no ,and i want to draw this string (the root,and if value 0 it must to be in left,1 must be in the right like picture [aimed result].

```
begin
  ListCont := ListBox1.Count-1;
  {s:= ListCont+1; }
  f:=1;k:=1;
  {edit7.text:=inttostr(s); }
  For i:= 0 to ListCont do
  begin
    edit4.Text:=  ListBox1.Items.Strings[i];
      for j:=0 to  ListCont do
      if i<>j then
      begin
        edit5.text:= ListBox1.Items.Strings[j];
        if length(edit4.Text)<length(edit5.Text)then
          min:= length(edit4.Text)
        else  
          min:= length(edit5.Text) ;
        for k:=1   to min do
        { if (f =8) then }
        { begin }
        if edit4.Text[k]=edit5.text[k] then
          f:=1
        else
          f:=0;
        if f=1 then
        begin
          edit6.text:='there is prefix ';
          exit;
        end;
      end;
      f:=0;
      edit6.Text:='the correct wordcodes';
    end;
  end;
end.
```

[image: aimed result]
[image: prefix codeword]

Comment: Have you looked at TTreeView in the OLH?

Comment: No, what is the OLH and TTree please?

Comment: OLH = Online Help, which comes with every version of Delphi.  Which Delphi version are you using?  TTreeView (not "TTree") is a standard Delphi component (on the Win32 tab of its component palette) which implements a GUI tree (which would otherwise be a monumental task).  It is up to you, as programmer, to populate it with nodes as appropriate to your task.  On SO (btw, welcome), we do not write your code for you - you need to try and write it yourself and ask when you get stuck.  So read up about TTreeView, and ask if you need to ...

Comment: thank you for your response i will try to solve it and  the version delphi 7 i use it.

Comment: In the D7 OLH, on the Search tab, type "ttreeview" and look at the "Add, Add Child example (Delphi)" which should be the 2nd entry in the results.

Comment: Please format your code ... it will help you and all others to get into your code

Comment: the idea that there was two edit text one for symbol like(a,b)and the other the stream of (0,1)and i must represent these symbol and 0,1 as alike show on the aimed result image.

Comment: You don't draw anything and your code is inscrutable. Surely you don't really let the IDE choose names for you? It seems like you need to try harder.

Comment: Plenty of examples here: http://delphi.about.com/od/ttreeview/

Comment: Treeview is not suitable for proper binary tree drawing (only weird H-V layout is possible). Consider some `Layered Tree Draw` algorithm http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~matya/Courses/AS09/chen_shay.ppt

Comment: thank you so much i will try

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem. I actually drew the tree myself on a descendant of the TPaintBox component, but you could just use a TPaintBox. The basic algorithm was to determine the height and width of the tree (I wanted the entire tree to be visible - you may not) then drew it as you might expect. I effectively divided it in to 2*N horizontal bands and drew the nodes on the odd numbered bands and lines on the even numbered bands.
The snippet below shows how to draw the tree

```
procedure TSigBTreeVCLHelper.DrawTree(pFromNode: TSigBTreeNode; const PaintBox: TPaintbox; const pLineHeight: integer; const pCurrLine: tRect; const DrawAll: boolean = TRUE);
var
  iLeftRect, iRightRect : tRect;
  iCentre : integer;
begin
  with pFromNode do
  begin
    DrawNode( pFromNode, Paintbox, pCurrLine );
    iCentre := (pCurrLine.Right + pCurrLine.Left) div 2;
    if assigned( LeftChild ) then
    begin
      iLeftRect.Top := pCurrLine.Top + 2 * pLineHeight;
      iLeftRect.Bottom := pCurrLine.Bottom + 2 * pLineHeight;
      iLeftRect.Left := pCurrLine.Left;
      iLeftRect.Right := iCentre;
      Paintbox.Canvas.MoveTo( iCentre, pCurrLine.Top + Paintbox.Canvas.TextHeight( 'X' ) + 2 );
      Paintbox.Canvas.LineTo( (iLeftRect.Left + iLeftRect.Right) div 2, iLeftRect.Top - 2);
      DrawTree( LeftChild, Paintbox, pLineHeight, iLeftRect, DrawAll );
    end;
    if assigned( RightChild ) then
    begin
      iRightRect.Top := pCurrLine.Top + 2 * pLineHeight;
      iRightRect.Bottom := pCurrLine.Bottom + 2 * pLineHeight;
      iRightRect.Left := iCentre;
      iRightRect.Right := pCurrLine.Right;
      Paintbox.Canvas.MoveTo( iCentre, pCurrLine.Top + Paintbox.Canvas.TextHeight( 'X' ) + 2 );
      Paintbox.Canvas.LineTo( (iRightRect.Left + iRightRect.Right) div 2, iRightRect.Top - 2);
      DrawTree( RightChild, Paintbox, pLineHeight, iRightRect, DrawAll );
    end;
  end;
end;
```

How you define and draw pNode is very much up to you. It depends on your implementation, but as you will see I assume that at least you define a left and right child.